# Can jconsole be used with Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx, jconsole

All the examples I see are for Java SE applications by passing your JAR file at the command line. Can JConsole attach to a WAR or EAR and monitor application performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JConsole is for monitoring JVMs. I'm assuming that you would like to monitor the performance of your application server. To do so, you'll have to set the com.sun.management.jmxremote property, when initializing your application server.

For example, in Tomcat (I know this is not a complete Java EE container), you would start the container as:

```
>startup.bat -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

You could then start JConsole as a standalone application

```
>jconsole
```

and then attach jconsole to the Java process that is running Tomcat.
Similar steps apply to other application servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat you should try [lambda probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org). It's a war file that once installed on tomcat enables a web-app with similar monitoring capabilities as jconsole.

On the lambda probe web there is also a JBoss download, but I only tested on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned jconsole monitors JVM, i.e. the whole application server instance and not specific web application deployed as war or ear.

If you are looking for more fine grained web app performance monitoring you could try to look at tools like [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) .